# Extracting dates from text using python and regular expressions where the dates are in the form october 12 - 2010

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the dates from the following text:

> Some text some more text October 12 - 2010

The result would be:

> yyyy-mm-dd: 2010-10-12

How can I tell regex the month is words and can be "january", "february" etc then a single space, [a group of 1-2 characters] a space and the final [group of four digits \d{4}]

Answer (score 0):

Writing out the actual names of the months in the regex makes for a very readable and maintainable expression, which I feel is important when it comes to regexes. Like so:

```
(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s\d{1-2}\s\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the above regular expression and calendar library to find calendar names, you can proceed as follows.

```
import calendar
import re
month_num = {v: str(k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_name)}
apattern = r'(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s\d{1,2}\s\-\s\d{4}'
re.sub(apattern, lambda x: 'yyyy-mm-dd:' + x.group().split(" ")[-1]+"-"+x.group().split(" ")[-3] + "-" + month_num[x.group().capitalize().split(" ")[0]], 'october 12 - 2010')
```